# Draw dynamic lines using html and css

Tags: html, css, dynamic, line, draw

Is it possible to draw the following using html and css?

[image]
[image]

I am interested only in lines part. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dx09uatq/7/) is what I tried so far.

html:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="topPart">
      TOP
    </div>
    <div class="middlePart">
      <div class="program selectedProgram">
        <div class="programName">
          foo program
        </div>

        <div class="modulesDiv">
          <div class="module">
           <div class="moduleName">
             foo module foo module foo module foo module foo module
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="module">
           <div class="moduleName">
             foo short name
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="module">
           <div class="moduleName">
             foo module foo module foo module foo module foo module
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomPart">
      BOTTOM
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-image: url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.inner {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px/* 100vh */
  ;
}

.topPart {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
}

.middlePart {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 10%;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

.bottomPart {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 90%;
  background-color: #66aa11;
  text-align: center;
}

.program {
  height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #afadad;
  position: relative;
}

.program.selectedProgram {
  border-left: 4px solid #289efd;
}

.program .programName {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #484646;
  padding-left: 5%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.selectedProgram.program .programName {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #289efd;
}

.program:hover .programName {
  color: #289efd;
}

.program .programName {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;
  white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
}

.modulesDiv {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  display: none;
}

.selectedProgram .modulesDiv {
  display: block;
}

.module {
  height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: relative;
}

.program .moduleName {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #484646;
  padding-left: 5%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.selectedModule.module .moduleName {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #289efd;
}

.module:hover .moduleName {
  color: #289efd;
}
```

There are two problems I am facing here.

1. I do not know how to draw a randomly positioned line using only `html` and `css`.
2. I can not guess beforehand how much height will each module take and hence can not infer in code when I will have to draw a horizontal prong to the module name.

I refer the main name, which is in bold in screenshot as a program name and names which are indented from left as module names.

I hope someone will be able to help at least with something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to implement the details but you could use a well organised structure combined with `background` size to create the effect you are looking for. I am using a single-pixel SVG background image that you can stretch with `background-size` to generate the look you want. It also does not sacrifice the actual semantics:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background: url( "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 1 1' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xml:space='preserve' preserveAspectRatio='none'><rect x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' fill='gray' stroke='none' /></svg>" );
  background-size: 1px calc(100% - .5em);
  background-position: top 0 left 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

li {
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: url( "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 1 1' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xml:space='preserve' preserveAspectRatio='none'><rect x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' fill='gray' stroke='none' /></svg>" );
  background-size: 8px 1px;
  background-position: top .5em left 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1>List</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Lipsum Dolor</li>
  <li>
    Sit Amet:
    <ul>
      <li>Dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Ipsum</li>
      <li>Datia</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Other</li>
</ul>
```

Going a little further to make the last item not stretch like crazy we will have to use multiply `background` definitions, so this cannot be made compatible with some older browsers, but it works regardless:

```css
ul, h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}


li {
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 13px;
  background: url( "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 1 1' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xml:space='preserve' preserveAspectRatio='none'><rect x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' fill='gray' stroke='none' /></svg>" ), url( "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 1 1' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xml:space='preserve' preserveAspectRatio='none'><rect x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' fill='gray' stroke='none' /></svg>" );
  background-size: 8px 1px, 1px 100%;
  background-position: top .5em left 5px, top 0 left 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}

li:last-of-type {
  background-size: 8px 1px, 1px .5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>List</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Lipsum Dolor</li>
  <li>
    Sit Amet:
    <ul>
      <li>Dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Ipsum</li>
      <li>Datia</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<h1>'Nother List</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Lipsum Dolor</li>
  <li>
    Sit Amet:
    <ul>
      <li>Dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Ipsum</li>
      <li>Datia</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Lipsum Dolor<br />Sit Amet Nanaba</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How could you solve the problem if the last `li` takes more than one line? For example, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dx09uatq/21/).

Comment: @iloveseven Yes but things get slightly more complicated. In that case all your padding needs to go to the <li>, and you need two background images. Let me try to make you a little example.

Comment: @iloveseven I have added a little snippet with a slightly different approach - I think this one is even better but it requires support for multiply backgrounds (which most browsers have at this point!). Then you can focus on the last child (or of-type) and end the list there. You can solve a lot of these edge cases in this fashion.

Comment: The lines you draw are drawn using svg\`s rect. I tried to tweak the `viewBox` and `width` and `height` attributes, adding the `stroke-width` and `stroke="black"` attributes, but it did not change the width of lines. Is it possible to change width of lines somehow?

Comment: @iloveseven Yes, using `background-size` properties :) The `<svg>`s are there simply to provide a square pixel of a certain color. Its just a 1x1 rectangle filled with a color (the svg is usually less code than using a `base64` encoded image)

Comment: Oh. That `background-size` trick is amazing. Thank you a lot. lol

Comment: I am really sorry for being so impertinent. But could you help setup the lines drawing in such a way, so that it would not draw lines below the selected `li`? I will attach the image in the question.